# SharePoint / WSS: How to localize a feature

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have a WSP package that contains some features.

I need to be able to localize the following in the features:

1. Site Column Field Display Names
2. Description of Content Types
3. List Instance Description
4. List Schema Fields

I am looking for a method to achieve all of this as easily as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its pretty easy- article describes it here: [read more](http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=70640fe5-28d9-464f-b1c9-91e07c8f7e47&ID=39)

I am using WSP Builder, So in my VS Project I created a Resources Subfolder, and I am hoping that the resources I add here will get deployed when the WSP Package is....

That's the theory, I will update this question if it works!

Answer (score 2):

In short, create a Resources folder inside of your feature folder, then add a text file to it, name it `Resources.en-US.txt` rename the file from `.txt` to `.resx`.

I use this roundabout way because I don't want the .designer.cs file and i don't want the schema part in my resx file. Which is what you get when you add a normal Resources file.

Open the resx file using the xml editor (right click -> open with) and add your properties in the following format:

```
<root>
  <data name="ANYNAME">
    <value>Some value</value>
  </data>
  <data name="ANOTHERNAME">
    <value>Some value</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

now you can use `$Resources:ANYNAME` etc. in your feature.xml i.e.

```
<feature Title="$Resources:ANYNAME" Description="$Resources:ANOTHERNAME" />
```

Comment: $Resources:MyResourceFileName,ANYNAME would be correct, if you don't set DefaultResourceFile...? Or not?

Comment: MyResourceFileName is only needed when you deploy to 12\Resources. When using feature related resources in a folder named resources in the feature folder, it is not needed.

Comment: What if you use the standard, visual studio resource files , will these work as well?

Comment: I now you said you didn't want the standard resource files, but what is your motivation for not wanting them, personal preference, or will it simply not work that way?

Comment: Whenb I tried they didn't work when i left the schema part in the .resx files. After removing the schema part so only the root -> data part remained, they did work.